# How far can you see in this forest?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Suppose that each point $(x,y)$ in the plane, both of whose coordinates are rational numbers, represents a tree. If you are standing at the point $(0,0)$, how far could you see in this forest?

Wouldn't the answer be you couldn't see far at all (because $\frac{y-0}{x-0}=\frac{y}{x}$)? Any direction you turned to would be blocked by a tree.

Comment: We better chop the tree at $(0,0)$ first as otherwise the notion of seeing anywhere from within a tree might make things difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Au contraire*! You could actually see *infinitely* far in such a forest. Consider this: if your vision is blocked by a tree (at the *rational* point $(a,b)$, for instance), then the slope of the line of sight from you to this tree is $\frac{b-0}{a-0}=\frac{b}{a}$, which is a rational number. Ah, but if you look along a line of *irrational* slope, then you will see infinitely far (the rational/irrational difference is the point of the problem, I think).

Comment: Infinitely far in infinitely many directions, in fact, as we may select an infinitude of irrational slopes.

Comment: @walkar Precisely.